# Python and SpaCy - cannot download specific version

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I am using Python `3.7.7`

I ran the following (after `pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz`) and got results

```
[XXXXX@localhost some-folder]$ python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm-2.2.0
2021-02-16 17:58:24.921639: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-16 17:58:24.921671: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine. Ignoring the CUDA*.

No compatible package found for 'en_core_web_sm-2.2.0
```

the only way I have made it to work is to remove the version `2.2.0` from the code. But SpaCy documentation suggests that the version number should be able to download the correct file.

So, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Run `pip3 freeze | grep [s]pacy` to see what version of space you have. You must have an incompatible spacy version.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew      I have corrected some info in my question. Updated

Answer (score 0):

Your spacy version also matters, not only the Python version.

[spaCy models-languages compatibility](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/blob/master/compatibility.)

If you are already using spaCy v3, you won't be able to download language versions < 3